# What is an example of an ICO or Crowdsale that used the Open Zeppelin RefundVault contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ico, crowdsale, openzeppelin

I am trying to understand the [RefundVault.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/distribution/utils/RefundVault.sol) contract from Open Zeppelin for implementing a soft cap that would refund investors if the cap is not reached. I am struggling t wrap my head around it, particularly how the enum for State works and how the crowdsale can interact with the contract to effect the mapping for deposited.

I thought that seeing a working example of this implemented would help but I can't find any. Does anyone have any links to code that use either this, or some other method for a soft cap refund functionality?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi John, could you elaborate more on which part of RefundVault is confusing you?

Comment: For example, when you create a new RefundVault inside of the crowdsale you pass in an address in the constructor. What address should this be? Should I create an ethereum wallet address to act as the wallet for the RefundVault? 
How does this then keep the funds locked if I have created the wallet?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Also the close() function has the line:
    `wallet.transfer(this.balance);`
Where is this transferring to, and from?

Thanks again, the concepts in this contract are new to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, when you create a new RefundVault inside of the crowdsale
>   you pass in an address in the constructor. What address should this
>   be?

That's the crowdsale's `wallet` address.

The [`Crowdsale`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.7.0/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol) contract has a `wallet` state variable storing the addess to which the funds raised will be sent. The [`RefundVault`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.7.0/contracts/crowdsale/distribution/utils/RefundVault.sol) contract used by the [`RefundableCrowdsale`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.7.0/contracts/crowdsale/distribution/RefundableCrowdsale.sol) works as a vault for storing the funds until the crowdsale ends and decides whether to send the funds to the crowdsale's `wallet` address or refund the buyers depending on if the goal was reached or not.

> Should I create an ethereum wallet address to act as the wallet for
>   the RefundVault?

You need to generate an ethereum address under your control (this is, you have to own the associated private key) and pass it to the crowdsale on construction.

> How does this then keep the funds locked if I have created the wallet?

Because the `RefundableCrowdsale` doesn't send the funds to the wallet but to the `RefundVault` instead. After the crowdsale, only if successful, the `RefundVault` will send the funds to the wallet you own. It's an intentional indirection to protect buyers in case of an unsuccessful crowdsale.

> Also the close() function has the line: wallet.transfer(this.balance);
>   Where is this transferring to, and from?

The [`transfer`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#address-related) method of the `address` type takes an `uint256` parameter and it sends that amount of wei from the caller to the address on which the method is called. In this case the caller (`RefundVault`) is sending all the wei in the contract (`this.balance`) to the `wallet` address.